# KeyError handling while consuming API

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I am consuming the Yelp API and using this detail view to display details of individual restaurants such as the name, rating and price of a restaurant. The detail dictionary is solid for the most part and lets me collect variables to use as context in template. However some restaurants do not provide their 'price' to the API, therefore when accessing this view I get a KeyError because there is no price in some cases. How can I create this dictionary with a None value for price to avoid this error? Or is exception handling with try & except the best solution?

```
def detail(request, api_id):
    API_KEY = 'unique_key'
    url = 'https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/'+ api_id
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(API_KEY)}

    req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    parsed = json.loads(req.text)

    detail = {
    'id': parsed['id'],
    'name': parsed['name'],
    'rating':parsed['rating'],
    'price': parsed['price'],
    }

    context = {'detail': detail}
    return render(request, 'API/detail.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<dict>.get('key', default_value)`:

```
detail = {
    'id': parsed['id'],
    'name': parsed['name'],
    'rating':parsed['rating'],
    'price': parsed.get('price', None),  # <-- here
}
```

[W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_get.asp) has a nice example on how to use `.get()` method.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
    detail = {
    'id': parsed['id'],
    'name': parsed['name'],
    'rating':parsed['rating'],
    'price': parsed['price'] if parsed['price'] else None,
    }
```